# How to reset the content URL for MPMoviePlayerController when playing a video?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-4.2, xcode3.2, xcode4.2

I want to reset the content URL for the MPMoviePlayerController object when playing a video.

on a button click, I am setting the content URL like below,

```
[videoPlayer setContentURL:url];
```

But i am getting the "Bad Access" error.

Is there a way to change the url when a movie player is already playing a video? 
It should stop the previous video and should start the video for the new url.

Answer (score 1):

It means you didn't allocate memory to videoplayer

```
MPMoviePlayerController * videoplayer = [MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[videoplayer setcontenturl: url];
```

it will not give you any error.